# How to use regex to format input number as string?

Tags: c++, regex

I want to take a number input as a string and then strip redundant zeroes. I've done this using substring but was wondering if there's a way to do it using regex. For example, regex replace.

I only use a regex to check if the string is a valid number or not. I use substring and if conditions repeatedly for the strippings. I want to be able to convert say: "0012340.3200E6" to "12340.32E6" using regex.

```
rr("((\\+|-)?[[:digit:]]+)(\\.(([[:digit:]]+)?))?((e|E)((\\+|-)?)[[:digit:]]+)?");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would be much better off converting the number into a float and then use string formatting, i.e. using

```
char buffer [50];
sprintf(buffer, "%E", ...)
)
```

or `spritnf(buffer, "%fE%d", ..., ...)` if for whatever you're doing this should work better.

Anyways, the regex should look something like

```regex
([+-]?)0*(\d+)(?:(\.\d*[1-9])|\.)0*(?:([Ee][+-]?)0*(\d+))?
```

(see [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/m28ca4/1)) and the substitution pattern would then be

```
$1$2$3$4$5
```

so you have everything in matching groups except the zeros and then you replace it with the content of all matching groups.

What's left is to escape the above expression and deal with the `\d` for digits – I've seen you're using `[[:digit:]]` instead.

Comment: Thank You for your answer. I can't actually store it in a float since I'm gonna store the string in a vector and thus the number can be arbitrarily large. I'm doing the stripping so the vector storage is simplified.

But the regex solution you provided is really helpful. Thank You. I can modify it to suit my needs. I'm a noob at regex sry.